# Slickgrid editor unavailable after grid.SetColumns()

Tags: editor, slickgrid

I am storing a column arrangement on a database. First I use grid.GetColumns() to retrieve the arrangement object and store it on a database using ajax post.

Then I retrieve it and apply it after the grid is loaded using  grid.SetColumns(data), where data is the arrangement restored as an object.

The columns get to correct order and width, but when I try to edit a cell, the editor does not open.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just "store" a pointer/reference in a database.  The column `editor` option is a reference to the editor constructor.  The same applies to the `formatter` and a ton of other options.